# How to set the hint of autocomplete textview in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Hi I want to add the `AutoCompleteTextview` in demo project where I am looking to set the hint as like we can do in `EditText`.

I know this is possible in `EditText` using `hint` property but I don't know how this can be done in `AutoCompleteTextiview.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set this in the xml file using

```
android:hint="yourHint"
```

like so.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordEntry"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [attr_android:completionHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:completionHint) for `AutoCompleteTextview`s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same property as you would with an EditText element.

```
android:hint="Password"
```

Comment: This type of answer would be more suited to a comment as it does not directly solve the question